# Meaning of trailing stream manipulator in C++ expression

Tags: c++, iostream, manipulators

What is the difference between both expressions of each pair ?
I don't understand the effect of the trailing `std::dec` at the end of those expressions.

**With `cin`**, between this :

```
int i;
std::cin >> std::hex >> i >> std::dec;
```

and this :

```
int i;
std::cin >> std::hex >> i;
```

**Same question with `cout`**, between this :

```
int i;
std::cout << std::hex << i << std::dec << std::endl;
```

and this :

```
int i;
std::cout << std::hex << i << std::endl;
```

Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some flags set by manipulators are only active for the next output or input operation.

Others, like the formatting flags set by `std::hex` or `std::dec` are set permanently in the stream object, and affects all output and input operations after setting the flag.

So if you use `std::hex` then all integer output and input from that point will be in hexadecimal notation. If you just want to output or input a single number in hexadecimal then you need to "reset" to the default decimal notation using e.g. `std::dec` leading to statements like

```
std::cin >> std::hex >> i >> std::dec;
```

Comment: Is it working in the same order for the first `std::cout` example or in the opposite order? I mean, is the `std::dec` read first or last in the expression, leaving the standard output with decimal or hexadecimal formatting at the end of the expression?

Comment: @A.Gille It always goes from left to right. Otherwise something such as `std::cout << "foo" << "bar"` would output `"barfoo"`. That you "output" (or "input") an manipulator expression doesn't matter, it's really no different than outputting (or inputting) a value.

Answer (score 1):

The `std::dec` sets the formatting of numbers in the stream for later use, in the same way that `std::hex` sets the formatting for the in-/output of i.

Comment: So if I use `std::hex` in my expression, the default formatting for `std::cin` or `std::cout` will remain hexadecimal formatting in the rest of the code until I use another manipulator?

Comment: Yes, this is the case for all streams that support these modifiers (stringstreams, fstreams etc.).